# undefined method `authenticate' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a method "attempt_login" as given below:

```
def attempt_login
  if params[:username].present? && params[:password].present?
      found_user= AdminUser.where(:username=> params[:username].first)
  if found_user
    authorized_user= found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
  end
end
if authorized_user
  flash[:notice]="You are now logged in."
  redirect_to(:action=>'menu')
else
   flash[:notice]="Invalid username/password combination."
   redirect_to(:action=>'login')
  end
end
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
 ←[1m←[35mAdminUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users`
  WHERE `admin_users`.`username` = 'u'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>)
:
  app/controllers/access_controller.rb:13:in `attempt_login'
```

It is working from rails console, but not from rails server.
 please tell me the solution, i am waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistake in your code, this:

```
found_user = AdminUser.where(:username => params[:username].first)
```

should be:

```
found_user = AdminUser.where(:username => params[:username]).first
```

Look in to the log:

```
SELECT `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users`
WHERE `admin_users`.`username` = 'u'
```

`params[:username].first` return first character from `params[:username]` but you need first record:

```
AdminUser.where(:username=> params[:username]).first
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by).

Rails 3:

`AdminUser.find_by_username(params[:username])`

Rails 4:

`AdminUser.find_by(username: params[:username])`